# Dropbox Image URLs not rendering in my app on mobile (iOS Chrome) as <img src="">

Tags: node.js, reactjs, mobile, dropbox

I have an app that fetch's dropbox image url's and displays them on screen. The app is React, node.js, and urls stored with MongoDB.

I have the url's set to "raw=1" and they render properly on desktop. But when I try the app on mobile (iOS, Chrome) all I see is the alt text.

I've tested adding a photo to the source code directory and this is rendering properly on mobile (same size, same CSS, same html attributes), which leads me to believe mobile isnt properly rendering the dropbox urls.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I read this forum on dropbox, if you scroll down it says that you have add the image in the public folder, i am not sure if it will work, but give it a try :)

Here is the link to the [forum](https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/Dropbox-files-folders/How-do-I-embed-images-with-a-direct-link-from-Dropbox/td-p/245432)

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks for the response! No luck with this, no option to make a folder public in dropbox for a free account - these url's are displaying perfectly on desktop, just not on mobile. And if I move an image to the root directory and add its path as the <img src>, it renders on mobile fine

Comment: When u moved your image to the root directory doesn't render on both devices

Comment: yep, once the files were located in the root directory it rendered on both Mobile and desktop